# How to prove $(\space|\sin n|\space)$ does not converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

How do we prove that $(\space|\sin n|\space)$ is not convergent ? There is a beautiful proof of the non-convergence  of $(\sin n)$ by considering the identities $\sin (n+1)=\cos1\sin n+ \sin 1 \cos n $ ,

$\cos (n+1)=\cos1\cos n- \sin 1 \sin n $ and $ \sin^2 n+\cos^2n=1$ , is there a similar proof for $(\space|\sin n|\space)$ ? (though at least any kind of proof will be helpful)

Comment: The fact that $n\mod\pi/2$ (likely proved often in this forum) is dense in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ implies that $|\sin(n)|$ is often close to $0$ and often close to $1$.

Comment: See also the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341378/).

Comment: Pick integers in the intervals centered about odd multiples of $\pi/2$ of length $1$. This will give you a subsequence bounded below by some $\alpha>0$.  Now pick integers centered about multiples of $\pi$ of length $1$. This will give you a subsequence bounded above by some $\beta<\alpha$.

Comment: [Strongly related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967548/how-to-show-that-sinn-does-not-converge)

Comment: [Better related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27218/prove-that-the-limit-of-sin-n-as-n-rightarrow-infty-does-not-exist?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove that $\left|\sin n\right|$ is not convergent in the same spirit. Assuming that $\left|\sin n\right|\to c\in[0,1]$, then the sequence given by:
$$ a_n = \cos(2n) = 1-2\sin^2 n$$
converges to $1-2c^2$. However:
$$ a_{n+1}-a_n = -2\sin(1)\sin(2n+1), $$
so assuming that $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence we must have $c=0$.
However, by assuming that $\sin n$ is close to zero we have that $\sin(n+1)$ *cannot be* close to zero, since from $\left|\sin n\right|\leq\varepsilon$ it follows that:
$$\sin(n+1)=\cos(1)\sin n \pm \sin(1)\sqrt{1-\sin^2 n},$$
$$\left|\sin(n+1)\right| \geq \sin(1)-2\varepsilon>\frac{5}{6}-2\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We know $\sin(x)$ and $|x|$ are continuous functions, and so $|\sin(x)|$ is a continuous function. Can you find this limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}|\sin(x)|$? It does not exists. Do you want to see the proof? Try to apply Cauchy's condition of infinite limite.

Apply the sequential criterion of continuity and see $|\sin(n)|$ does not exists.