# How to show that $\sin(n)$ does not converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am supposed to show that $\sin(n)$ does not converge by constructing two subsequences: one subsequence contains terms of $\sin(n)$ that are between $1/2$ and $1$, and the other subsequence contains terms of $\sin(n)$ that are between $-1/2$ and $-1$. But how can I do this? Which $k(n)$--for subsequence $x_{k(n)}$--should I choose?

Comment: Wellcome to MSE. If you make your question clear and show your
trial, then you would obtain an ideal feedback. And if you have
asking and answering, then you will get several badges and points.
Nice to meet you.

Comment: Consider a function
 $ f: {\bf Z}\rightarrow [0,2\pi],\ k\mapsto k\ ({\rm mod}\ 2\pi)$.
 As far as I know, ${\rm Im}\ (f) $ is $dense$ in $[0,2\pi]$. But I
 cannot prove and it may be in graduate level.

Comment: Actually, a better dupliate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27218/prove-that-the-limit-of-sin-n-as-n-rightarrow-infty-does-not-exist?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $I_k=[2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{6},2k\pi+\frac{5\pi}{6}]$, the length is $\frac{2\pi}{3}>1$, then there must $\exists  n_k\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $n_k\in I_k$. (Here we use the property that $\forall a>0, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$,s.t. $a\leq n<a+1$.) Thus for each $k$, we find such $n_k$, s.t $\sin n_k>\frac{1}{2}$.

Similarly for $I_k^{'}=[2k\pi+\frac{7\pi}{6},2k\pi+\frac{11\pi}{6}]$. We get a subsequence $\{\sin n_k^{'}\}<-\frac{1}{2}$. Hence we can find find two subsequences don't converge to the same value. The whole sequence can't converge.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need to split sequence into two subsequences here, as an expression for finding sign of $\sin(n)$ doesn't look elegant for $n \in \mathbb N$.  I think it's better to prove the problem with the help of Cauchy's convergence test:
Let $a_n = \sin n$ converge to $L$. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N(\epsilon) > 0, \forall n,m > N(\epsilon) : |a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$.
Let $m = n + 1$. Then $|a_n - a_m| = |\sin n - \sin (n+1)| = |2\sin\frac 12 * \cos\frac{2n+1}{2}| = 2\sin\frac 12|\cos \frac {2n+1}{2}|$. This expression should be less than $\epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$ starting from some $N(\epsilon)$ but cosine always take values from $[-1,1]$. We came to a contradiction $\Rightarrow (a_n)$ does not converge.